# Poisson process with different rates

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I want to simulate the heart attacks happening in a year, and after research, I figured it can be generated using the Poisson process, where the time difference between two heart attacks is exponentially distributed, with the assumption that it is only related to the time of the day rather than months or day of the week.

The problem is that heart attacks (according to my data) happen more often in the afternoon. My question is how to do the Poisson process with a different rate for each time segment?
I am not a mathematician and unfamiliar with many terms or (the right way), therefore I thought of doing Poisson for each hour and append them in the final code, or is there a formula or method for my problem?

Comment: An [inhomogeneous Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Inhomogeneous_Poisson_point_process) process might work here. This with a 24-hour periodic intensity function $\lambda(t)$. This function must then be close to constant but must grow a bit in the afternoon time.

Comment: As an example of a particularly simple 'industry standard' inhomogeneous Poission Process, credit derivatives modelling has used piecewise constant hazard rate (i.e. intensity) 'curves' for over a couple of decades (except where stochastic intensities are required), to calibrate probabilities of corporate default. You would be looking to calibrate different piecewise flat intensities to match the diurnal pattern of cumulative heart attack frequency in your data for example.